# What tools are available or being developed for cross-chain operations?

Tags: blockchain-interoperation, sidechain

Are there any headways being made for BTC, ETH, other blockchains cross-talk?

Answer (score 0):

[Blockstream](https://blockstream.com/) for Sidechains: A sidechain is a blockchain that validates data from other blockchains and enables other assets to be transferred between blockchains.

[Interledger](https://interledger.org/): The protocol for connecting blockchains.

[Blocknet](http://blocknet.co/): The Blocknet is a revolutionary advancement in cryptographic technology: a true peer-to-peer protocol between nodes on different blockchains. This is the foundation of a technology stack incorporating an API and an application platform, which enables open-ended application possibilities and vastly reduces development time.

Note: I haven't tested any of these services.